# Dynamic CSS for SVG

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

In angular, I am displaying an SVG:

```
<div [innerHTML]="svgImage" class="center">
</div>
```

The SVG contains polygons with a unique ID, for example:

```
<polyline id="tp_31" fill="#FFFAEC" points="698.814,494.607 719.188,459.31 698.813,424.014 658.064,424.015 637.69,459.313
        658.065,494.608 698.814,494.607     "/>
```

I am able to style each polygon individually in the SCSS file with an id selector:

```
#tp_31:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

However, I am not sure how to do this dynamically. The SVG image will be coming from a server and I would like to style it programatically. How can I best achieve this? I've tried using `[ngStyle]` but I am not sure how to use it with an id selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can interact with DOM directly

```
import { ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const svgElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#tp_31');
    if (svgElement) {
        svgElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            svgElement.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
        });
        svgElement.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            svgElement.setAttribute('fill', '#FFFAEC');
        });
    }
}
```

your second option is using render

```
import { Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const svgElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#tp_31');
    if (svgElement) {
        this.renderer.listen(svgElement, 'mouseover', () => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(svgElement, 'fill', 'blue');
        });
        this.renderer.listen(svgElement, 'mouseout', () => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(svgElement, 'fill', '#FFFAEC');
        });
    }
}
```